# the fastest way to replace (and store in array) links in the text with their order numbers

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, preg-match

There is a `$str` string that may contain html text including `<a >link</a>` tags.

I want to store links in array and set the proper changes in the $str.

For example, with this string:

```
$str="some text <a href='/review/'>review</a> here <a class='abc' href='/about/'>link2</a> hahaha";
```

we get:

```
linkArray[0]="<a href='/review/'>review</a>";
positionArray[0] = 10;//position of the first link in the string

linkArray[1]="<a class='abc' href='/about/'>link2</a>";
positionArray[1]=45;//position of the second link in the string

$changedStr="some text [[0]] here [[1]] hahaha";
```

Is there any faster way (the performance) to do that, than running through the whole string using `for`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done by preg_match_all with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE FLAG.

e.g.

```
$str="some text <a href='/review/'>review</a> here <a class='abc' href='/about/'>link2</a> hahaha";
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",$str,$out,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

var_dump($out);
```

Here the output array is `$out`. `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` captures the offset in the string where the pattern starts.

The above code will output:

```
array (size=2)0 => 

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '<a href='/review/'>review</a>' (length=29)
      1 => int 10
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '<a class='abc' href='/about/'>link2</a>' (length=39)
      1 => int 45
1 => 

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'review' (length=6)
      1 => int 29
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'link2' (length=5)
      1 => int 75
```

for more information you can click on the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

for $changedStr:
let $out be the output string from preg_match_all

```
$count= 0;
foreach($out[0] as $result) {

$temp=preg_quote($result[0],'/');

$temp ="/".$temp."/";
$str =preg_replace($temp, "[[".$count."]]", $str,1);


$count++;   
}
var_dump($str);
```

This gives the output :

```
string 'some text [[0]] here [[1]] hahaha' (length=33)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about $changedStr though?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to do such, check this:

http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php

try them here:

http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

And use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Find your best regular expression to solve every case you may find: preg_match_all, if you set the pattern correctly, will return you an array containing every link you desire.

Edit:

In your case, assuming you want to keep the "`<a>`", this may work:

```
$array = array();    
preg_match_all('/<a.*.a>/', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Input example:

```
<a href="ciccio">test</a>
<a href="caio">Lkdlasdk</a>

llkdla

<a href="lol">xx</a>
```

Output with the above regexp:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="ciccio">test</a>
            [1] => <a href="caio">Lkdlasdk</a>
            [2] => <a href="lol">xx</a>
        )

)
```

Hope this helps